# Pyspark - Classification Implementation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a use case to predict the Multi Class labeled value. I have basic doubts in data preparation using Pyspark Implementation.

Let say I have the below dataset:

```
A      B      C      Label
10   class1  Boy    Cricket  
12   class3  Boy    Football
11.6 class2  Girl   Hockey
..
..
..
..
12.2 class1 Girl   Hockey
```

This is my dataset where except feature A, everything is categorical.

Lets say we are using Decision Tree classifier for Multi Class prediction.

I have did this data preparation steps:

**Step1**: Min Max normalizer for feature A

**Step2**: String Indexer for feature A,B,C

**step3**: One-Hot encoded transform for feature A,B,C

Now, the transformed dataframe looks like,

```
A     B        B_Indexed_transformed   C    C_Indexed_transformed   Label
0.86  Class1    [5,1,[1.0,1.0]]        Boy   [2,1,[1.0,1.0]]        Cricket
.
.
.
```

Next, I will keep A, B_Indexed_transformed, C_Indexed_transformed, label columns and drop all other columns.

**Step4**: Create LabeledPoint data with [Label, Features] Pair

So, my question is, in order to pass this data to the Decision Tree Algorithm (or any other Classifier), **do I need to do any transformation to the Label column**.

I have done String Indexing for the Label column. Is this the right way to do?

When I pass the string indexed label column to LabeledPont transformation, I am facing this error:

```
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1293, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rddsampler.py", line 95, in func
  File "/hba01/yarn/nm/usercache/sbeathanabhotla/appcache/application_1498495374459_1420410/container_1498495374459_1420410_01_000001/build.zip/com/ci/roletagging/service/ModelBuilder.py", line 17, in <lambda>
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.label = float(label)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

If I pass the Label data as it as string without any transformation, I face this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1293, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rddsampler.py", line 95, in func
  File "/hba06/yarn/nm/usercache/sbeathanabhotla/appcache/application_1498495374459_1425329/container_1498495374459_1425329_01_000001/build.zip/com/ci/roletagging/service/ModelBuilder.py", line 17, in <lambda>
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p0.2/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.label = float(label)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: businessevaluator
```

Comment: Pls provide the code producing the above errors, along with the relevant Spark imports

Comment: Also, if you intend to use Spark MLlib or Spark ML for your multinomial classification